# Какк получить loggedInUser.login для правила?

Tags: jetbrains, workflow, youtrack

Как определенному авторизированному пользователю подсунуть свой шаблон и есть ли порядок применение правил в youtrack WorkFlow?

Пытался сделать так, но что-то не выходит:

```
rule one

when !isReported() && description == null && loggedInUser.login == "vpupkin" && Type == {Bug} { 
  description = "Вася Пупкин пишет:\n"; 
}
```

Помимо этого шаблона есть еще общий для всех. Я конечно не уверен, но может быть общее правило применяется быстрее и подсовывает ему общий шаблон, вместо кастомного. Но где посмотреть порядок применения правил я что-то не нашел.